# How would I arrange divs in a responsive grid? (Wolfram.com style)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically, how can I take multiple differently-heighted elements and 'push' them against the top of a container, like on [wolfram's homepage](http://wolfram.com)?

When I looked at their code, it appeared that they used a large amount of javascript, as well as absolute positioning, but it seems like there are easier ways to do it than that. How would one go about this?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Take a look at [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). It does the grid layout at the same time responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into a framework like [UI-Kit](http://getuikit.com/docs/grid-js.html) which allows you to do things like this pretty easily.

I don't believe there is a native CSS solution for this design, although you might want to take a look at FlexBox.